# Changing contents of an array via its reference

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, refcell

I've been recently working with the following scenario:

```
pub fn random_function(inp_array: &[u32]) {

    for actual_val in (RefCell::new(*inp_array)).iter_mut() {
        // change actual_val to e.g., constant number so that it's reflected in inp_array
    }
```

Given a function that takes as input a reference to an immutable u32 array, I'm trying to change its contents via a smart pointer. I'm still kind of new to interior mutability concept; the snipped above has the following issue:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u32]` cannot be known at compilation time
error[E0599]: no method named `iter_mut` found for struct `RefCell` in the current scope
```

I'm not entirely sure what is the correct pattern here. Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: You cannot change a `&[u32]` without causing U.B., you need to accept a `&RefCell<Vec<u32>>` or similar. (i.e. the interior mutability needs to be explicit in the arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change anything behind a shared reference unless it is *already* in a `UnsafeCell` (for example via `RefCell`). The most likely version you want is to take a mutable reference instead:

```rust
pub fn random_function(inp: &mut [u32]) {
    for actual_val in inp {
        // change actual_val to e.g., constant number so that it's reflected in inp_array
        *actual_val += 10;
    }
}
```

If you want to use interior mutability, the parts that you want to mutate have to be wrapped in a struct supporting that already. So you could take `&[RefCell<u32>]`

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
pub fn random_function(inp: &[RefCell<u32>]) {
    for actual_val in inp {
        // change actual_val to e.g., constant number so that it's reflected in inp_array
        *actual_val.borrow_mut() += 10;
    }
}
```

or `&RefCell<impl AsMut<[u32]>>`

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
pub fn random_function(inp: &RefCell<impl AsMut<[u32]>>) {
    for actual_val in inp.borrow_mut().as_mut() {
        // change actual_val to e.g., constant number so that it's reflected in inp_array
        *actual_val += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer clarifies the aspects I was missing. Indeed, rewriting upstream so that this could be a simple &mut array and not complicate things via cells is the most sensible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- *"takes as input a reference to an immutable u32"*
- *"trying to change its contents"*

Those two statements are incompatible. You cannot mutate a reference to an immutable variable without `unsafe`. And even then, it [would be unsound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html).

If your function needs to modify values in the `inp_array`, it must take it as an `&mut [u32]`.

You can of course use interior mutability for this purpose, but then the type must be a `&RefCell` or `&Mutex` or their respective ref-counted counterparts, `Rc<RefCell>` or `Arc<Mutex>`.